# print an html/css form on a legal size paper

Tags: html, css, forms, printing

I need to be able to print my form on an 8.5" x 11" piece of paper.  The form needs to have all the form fields blank.  Then my customers are going to sign the form.  I then need to be able to fill in all the form fields on the computer and then print all the form fields into the form.

How can i do it in html and css.

Answer (score 2):

You should design a form in a normal page, and use [CSS3 Media Styles](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html) to style the page for "print" format.  E.g.

```
 @media print {      /* Just for printer */
   body { font-size: 10pt }
 }

 @media screen {     /* Just for computer */
   body { font-size: 13px }
 }
```

[Codex - Styling for Print](http://codex.wordpress.org/Styling_for_Print) is a good blog post on setting up your page styles for print.

From there, you can easily add simple JavaScript to cause a print action:

```
 <a href="JavaScript:window.print();">Print this page</a>
```

or

```
 <body onload="JavaScript:window.print();">
```

Answer (score 1):

ghayes method would work.

But using CSS3 Media Styles is not supported in IE before 9 ( [More Info Here](http://caniuse.com/#search=med) )

But all browsers do support media types EX:

```
<link href="/css/print.css" media="print" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

I would stick to media types to for my Print Stylesheets.

I will give an example of a simple print stylesheet (one I use on my site)

```
/*
*********************************
* PRINT ONLY STYLES ***
*********************************
*/

/* TAGS */

html, body{
font-size:12pt !important; } /* !important Tags are to overide other CSS 
                                 when printed */

h1{ font-size:18pt !important; }
h2{ font-size:16pt !important; }
h3{ font-size:14pt !important; }
h4{ font-size:12pt !important; }
h5, h6{ font-size:10pt !important; }

* {color:#000 !important; } 


/* HIDE HEAD, FOOTER, AND SIDEBAR ELEMENTS */

#top, .social, #pre_footer_back_ground, #right_sidebar, .full_shadow, 
.slideshow, .light_button, .dark_button, .addthis_toolbox, img
{ display:none; }

/*SHOW PRINT ONLY AREAS*/
#logo-print, #copyright-print, #contact-print {display:block;}


/* DISPLAY ABSOLUTE LINKS */

a[href^="http://"]:after{content: " (" attr(href) ") ";}

a {text-decoration:none;}


/* FORMS FOR PRINT */

#form textarea, #form input, #form select{ border:1px solid #fff; color:#fff; }
#form textarea:focus, #form input:focus{ background-color:#fff; }

.form textarea, .form input, .form select{ border:1px solid #fff; color:#fff; }
.form textarea:focus, .form input:focus{ background-color:#fff; }

    #form, .form{ clear:both; }
#form form, .form form{ padding-top:10px; }
#form textarea{ float:right; margin-bottom:10px; padding:6px 5px 6px 5px; width:450px; height:130px; overflow:hidden; }
.form textarea{ float:right; margin-bottom:10px; padding:6px 5px 6px 5px; width:450px; height:130px; overflow:hidden; }
#form input{ float:right; margin-bottom:10px; padding:6px 5px 6px 5px; width:450px; font-size:13px; line-height:18px; }
.form input{ float:right; margin-bottom:10px; padding:6px 5px 6px 5px; width:450px; font-size:13px; line-height:18px; }
#form input, #form textarea, .form input, .form textarea{
    -moz-border-radius:3px;
    -webkit-border-radius:3px;
    border-radius:3px;
}

/* ETC Add your print only styles */
```

You can easily customize your forms to be able to only show the form and easily have the user print out the form. Then you would take that paper that is signed and fill in the information and run in through the printer again.

Might take a bit of work to get everything correct (like alignment etc) but it should not be super hard.

So basically create the form as you normally would (HTML) and style it (CSS) for your site then change the CSS in your print only style.

Hope this Helps. =>

Comment: Thanks for the nod and you make a good point!  [Media style support](http://caniuse.com/#search=media)